# urllib2 - ability skip certificate verification

Tags: python, ssl, urllib2

I need to simulate somehow option `-k` (vide `--insecure` to ignore SSL certificate verification) for `curl` but using `urllib2`. Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing special to do here. `urllib2` does not do SSL certificate verification by default. There is a warning in the documentation http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html

> Warning HTTPS requests do not do any verification of the server’s certificate.

Comment: What's a good urllib2 alternative that does SSL certificate verification?

Comment: Actually, it looks like httplib (or http.client in Python 3.0) provides an HTTPSConnection which skips verification.

Comment: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ is a popular library which does SSL verification by default.

Comment: Apperantly newer versions do:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268548/python-ignore-certicate-validation-urllib2

Comment: Yes this changed in Python 2.7.9.