# getting data from php script using python

Tags: php, python

I'm trying to get data from php script using a my python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'https://example.com/example.php'
data = urllib.urlencode({'login' : 'mylogin', 'pwd' : 'mypass', 'data' : 'mydata'})
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
d = response.read()
print d
```

doesn't run with error:

```
ERROR=1704
```

php script accepts:

```
url: https://example.com/example.php?login=xxxxxxx&pwd=xxxxxxx&t=3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it because it is https, as described in the most voted response here: [python ignore certicate validation urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268548/python-ignore-certicate-validation-urllib2)