# python substitution for curl --proxy-insecure

Tags: python, bash, proxy

I'm using a proxy which has self-signed SSL certificate. 
`curl` has a `--proxy-insecure` option which not check ssl of proxy for validation.

```
curl -x https://some.proxy.com --proxy-insecure  -I  https://www.somewebsite.now
```

I want to covert my code in python, 
so is there any substitution for `--proxy-insecure` in python?

Comment: How are you planning to make the request in Python? Using the `requests` library? Using the built in urllib library? Have you tried either to see if they care about the validity of the self-signed certificate already? Get the problem first, then ask how to fix it :-)

Comment: @MatsLindh I'm manipulating this app [link] (https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli) and it's using urllib2. I want to know how I can use my self-signed proxy in this app.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450132/proxy-with-urllib2 - you might also be able to set it using environment variables (i.e. `export` under nix, `set` under windows) and setting `https_proxy` to the proxy host.

Comment: You may take adavantage from [Python: Ignore certificate validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268548/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python ignore certificate validation urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268548/python-ignore-certificate-validation-urllib2)

Comment: @U880D unfortunately no. in your answer actually the ssl of the website is not going to be checked, although I want that the ssl of my proxy dont be checked

Answer (score -1):

with [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io):

```
pip3 install requests
```

and then:

```
import requests
requests.get('https://www.somewebsite.now', proxies={'https': 'https://some.proxy.com'}, verify=False)
```